# Equivalence of movvar matlab function using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matlab

What is the equivalence of `movvar(A, k, w)` MATLAB function that calculates the moving average using python/numpy/pandas?

I tried `pandas.rolling.mean()` using this example from Matlab documentation but the result is not consistent:

```
A= [4, 8, 6, -1, -2, -3, -1, 3, 4, 5]
a = pd.Series(A)

print(a.rolling(window=3).mean())

0         NaN
1    6.000000
2    4.333333
3    1.000000
4   -2.000000
5   -2.000000
6   -0.333333
7    2.000000
8    4.000000
9         NaN
dtype: float64

# using Matlab
M = movvar(A, k=3, w=1)

M = 1×10

4.0000    2.6667   14.8889   12.6667    0.6667    0.6667    6.2222    4.6667    0.6667    0.2500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `rolling.var` and specify `center=True` and `min_periods=1` in the `rolling` and `ddof=0` in the `var`

```
print(a.rolling(3, center=True, min_periods=1).var(ddof=0))
0     4.000000
1     2.666667
2    14.888889
3    12.666667
4     0.666667
5     0.666667
6     6.222222
7     4.666667
8     0.666667
9     0.250000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Sorry, It was  a typo in the result using matlab function. I put the output of `movvar(A, 3)` instead of `movvar(A, 3, 1)`. We normalize each variance by the number of element in the window

Comment: @BetterEnglish there's a [`ddof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.var.html) option you can pass to `var`.

Comment: Thank you @Ben.T

Comment: @Ben.T, how to discard endpoints as in `movvar(..., 'Endpoints', 'discard')`

Comment: @Ben.T, I find it:  `min_periods=3` and `closed='left'`

Comment: @BetterEnglish good job, not even time to see the first comment :p